# QObject connection function

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals

I checked other similar questions and tried their solutions but they don't work for me.

I'm basically trying to make a http client that only makes post requests. In order to do this, I need to connect `QNetworkManager`'s finished signal to some callback slot.

Here's my code.

*h file*:

```
...
public slots:
   void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *network_manager;
...
```

*cpp file*:

```
...
Class1::Class1(){
    network_manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(network_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply *)), this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply *)));
}
...
void Class1::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    // some logic with reply
}
...
```

As you can see, the slot is definitely present and it is declared under public slots in header file. So I have no idea why this is happening. I already tried clean, run qmake, and rebuild.

The error message is:

> "QObject::connect: No such slot QObject::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply
>   *)"

Any idea?

Comment: Notice that the error says **QObject**::finishedSlot. That means Qt doesn't know about your subclass. That means meta information about it wasn't generated. That means `moc` wasn't run on your class. That means your class is lacking the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

Comment: You must not forget to specify your slot function (in the header file) in the "slots:" area

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You probably forgot to use the [`Q_OBJECT`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#Q_OBJECT) macro. Every class that implements its own slots/signals needs that macro. Don't forget that you need to add your header/source file to the .pro file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also had to clean/qmake/rebuild after adding that.

Comment: @Charlemagne: Merely re-running quake on the project would have sufficed, I think. This can save time on large projects.

Answer (score 22):

One thing to note; since you're using Qt 5, there's a new signal slot connection syntax, which will allow you to specify any function and not just those defined as slots.

In this situation you can do this: -

```
connect(network_manager, &QNetworkAccessManager::finished, this, &Class1::finishedSlot);
```

What's great about this syntax is that you just specify the address of the function and don't bother about the parameters, so if you change them in a function, you don't need to update them in the connect statements.

You still should be using the Q_OBJECT macro though and you can read more about the new syntax [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax).

Comment: Could you tell us if such a function has to be declared as static?

Comment: The function does not need to be static, as a pointer to the instance is passed to the connect call.

Comment: Ouuuwww, you're right! Before `&Class1::finishedSlot` we pass `this`. I just forgot all my Qt experiences :).

Comment: @TheDarkKnight: Certainly helpful.! The error was just due to non-usage of this new syntax.

Answer (score 6):

I share another possible problem here as this post is the top most in google search.

In addition to add `Q_OBJECT`, you must also add `public slots:` or `public Q_SLOTS:`  for your customized event. Otherwise, you'll still encounter the `QObject::connect: No such slot` error.

I give a brief summary here according to [Zeta's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19886895/4780326) and [the other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657003)

To solve `“No such slot” error`, you must check..

> 1. Check if your class inherits `QObject` or any derived class from QObject
> 2. Append `Q_OBJECT` macro inside the class definition
> 3. Append `slots` or `Q_SLOTS` after your private/protected/public keyword for your event
> 4. If you do check 1-3, then **clean**, **run qmake**, and rebuild again to make sure all your things in 1-3 are generated by [moc](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/moc.html).

Finally, a example here:

```
class MyClass: public QObject { //check 1
     Q_OBJECT //check 2

   public slots: //check 3
     void onEvent(int);
};
```

Hope this saves others' life